# docker + nginx http requests not working in browsers

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I have a AWS EC2 instance running Linux with docker containers running gunicorn/django and an nginx reverse proxy.

I *don't* want it to redirect to https at the moment.

When I try to reach the url by typing out `http://url.com`  in  the browser it seems to automatically change to `https://url.com` and gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.  The request doesn't show up at all in the nginx access_log.

But when I try to reach it with curl I get a normal response and it does show up in the nginx access_log.

I have ascertained that the django security middleware is not the cause as the HSTS options are disabled.

I've tried clearing the browser cache and deleting the domain from the chrome security policies.

nginx config:

```
upstream django_server {
    server app:8001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name url.com www.url.com;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    charset utf-8;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    location /static/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/sdev/;
        expires 30d;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: I believe modern browsers auto redirect to use https.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://superuser.com/a/881431

Comment: @chrislondon as i mentioned i tried that already haha.  I've set up many websites and I've never had them redirect to https without a redirect/HSTS being configured.  Unless things changed in the last year or two.